# Что означает генерированный код workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Юзал чужой код. И наткнулся на:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';
```

Потом разобрался, что это код который генерирует workbench. 
Вопрос: *На что влияет, и как работет данный код? Спасибо.*

Answer (score 1):

Сохраняет настройки, и назначает новые, что бы ускорить процесс импорта/экспорта и что бы не вышли ошибки связанные с ключами.
Например тут

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS
```

Происходит сохранение в переменную

```
@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS
```

значение Уникальных ключей на данные момент это переменная

```
@@UNIQUE_CHECKS
```

А затем отключается проверка Уникальных ключей

```
UNIQUE_CHECKS=0
```